# How to load (image) file using REST API using Acces Token in authorization Bearer?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, jsforce, accesstoken

Using an access token I can successfully receive Query responses.

Now I would like to load an (image) file URL using the same method, but it returns a 302 redirect with JavaScript code to redirect (I believe to the login page?).

```
https://my-sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=JPG&versionId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&operationContext=CONTENT&contentId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&page=1
```

If I open a Guest window, log in to Salesforce, and go to this URL, it loads the image.

I would like to load the file contents through the REST API using GET. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to query image data through the REST API, using `GET`:

```
https://my-sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/services/data/v{api_version}.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/{content_version_id}/VersionData
```

Replace

- `{api_version}` with your API version
- `{content_version_id}` with your `ContentVersionId`.

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm)